# Nested foreach loop (3 items + 1 / loop)

Tags: php, foreach

I have a small issue I can't figure out (PHP beginner) with a nested `foreach` loop. What I want to achieve is a structure like this:

```
<div class="slide-testimonials">
   <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
   <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
   <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
Sales People
<div class="slide-testimonials">
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
Freelancers
<div class="slide-testimonials">
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
Sales Managers
```

What I get now is this:

```
<div class="slide-testimonials">
   <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
   <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
   <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
Sales PeopleFreelancersSales Managers
<div class="slide-testimonials">
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
Sales PeopleFreelancersSales Managers
<div class="slide-testimonials">
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
    <span class="item"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
Sales PeopleFreelancersSales Managers
```

The foreach loop I'm using is this:

```
<?php 
    $post_type = 'testimonial';
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type );
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts p where p.post_type = 'attachment' AND (p.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%')  AND (p.post_status = 'inherit') AND p.post_parent IN (SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts  {$where} ) ORDER BY p.post_date DESC";
    $results =  $wpdb->get_results( $query );   
    $arrayName = array('title1' => 'Sales People', 'title2' => 'Freelancers', 'title3' => 'Sales Managers' );               
    $count = 0;
        foreach ($results as $image) {
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $image->ID );
            $alt = get_post_meta($image->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                if ($count % 3 == 0) {
                    echo "<div class='slide-testimonials'>";
                }
        $count++;
?>
<span class='item'> <?php print '<img class="image" src="' . $thumb . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />' ?> </span>
<?php
    if ($count % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</div>";
            foreach($arrayName as $value) {
            print $value;
            }
    }
}
?>
```

How can I loop through the `array` and print only one value on each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more counter `$nameCount` increase this in second `if` condition. `$nameCount = 1;` declare this in before `foreach` loop and use below code in second `if` condition.

```
if ($count % 3 == 0) {
   echo "</div>";echo $arrayName['title'.$nameCount];
   $nameCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this with your first loop:

```
foreach($results as $id=>$image) {
```

Then replace your second loop with:

```
echo $arrayName['title'.($id+1)];
```

Comment: In this case I only get the first value of the array. I should add another counter maybe?